# Horizontal composition and morphisms product

Tags: category-theory

Can the [horizontal composition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/horizontal+composition) be treated as [morphism product](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Product_of_Morphisms)?

Let $A,B,C,D$ are functors such that compositions $A \circ C, B \circ D$ are suitable. $\alpha: A \to B, \beta: C \to D$ are 2 natural transformations.

Consider $A,B,C,D$ as objects and $\alpha, \beta$ as morphisms.

1. Can the compositions $A \circ C, B \circ D$ be treated as the
   products of the corresponding objects (without any additional assumptions): $A \times C$ and $B \times D$? If not then is it possible if all of them are
   endofunctors of the same category?
2. If yes then what is the product of the morphisms $\alpha \times
   \beta$? Is it the horizontal composition $\alpha \star \beta$?

EDIT: The original question was about relations of the following pairs of operations:

1. $\times$ as product and $\times$ as morphisms product
2. $\circ$ as functors composition and $\star$ as horizontal
   composition

Both form bifunctors (aka tensor product) where the first operation is a mapping for objects and the second one can be treated as mapping for morphisms

Comment: I don't understand your notation. What are $A,B,C,D$?

Comment: They are functors. I will update my question with the exact info about then

Comment: I still don't understand the question. What does it mean that "the functor composition can be written as product"? You may denote anything by any symbol, but what is the reason to do this?

Comment: I. e. if functors are considered as objects, natural transformations as morphisms can I consider (in general without any additional assumptions) the functors composition as the product of the objects? (If not then I got the negative answer for my initial question).

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: @Ivan No, because a product of objects should be an object of the same category. In your question, as I understand, $A$, $C$ and $A\circ C$ are objects of different categories of functors. They may be so in the category of endofunctors, but in this case the composition is not a product in this category.

Comment: @Oskar thank you - You just provided me the required answer.